# How to apply ternary class (ng-class) using Angular?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a form validation and I learned how to do some simple validation stuffs I can get the error and display some error message. Now what I want is to display some style if the text inputs are properly inputted.

Here's a bit of my code:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-12" ng-class="{'has-error': noteForm.c_subject.$invalid && noteForm.c_subject.$touched }">
```

I want to apply the `has-success` class if there's no error. How can I do that?

Comment: Why don't you use angular's `ng-valid` class ? It automatically applies

Comment: Ok I will search for it Im still learning angular. :)

Comment: If there is no error, `noteForm.c_subject.$valid` will be true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just invert the condition? You can chain classes in ng-class with this syntax:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-12" 
    ng-class="{'has-error': noteForm.c_subject.$invalid && noteForm.c_subject.$touched, 
               'has-success': !noteForm.c_subject.$invalid || !noteForm.c_subject.$touched }">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="form-group col-md-12 {{(noteForm.c_subject.$invalid && noteForm.c_subject.$touched)? 'has-error': 'has-success'}}></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Update

```
ng-class="{'has-error': noteForm.c_subject.$invalid && noteForm.c_subject.$touched }"
```

To

```
ng-class ="{true: 'has-error', false: 'has-success'}[noteForm.c_subject.$invalid && noteForm.c_subject.$touched]"
```

i.e.

```
<div class="form-group col-md-12" ng-class ="{true: 'has-error', false: 'has-success'}[noteForm.c_subject.$invalid && noteForm.c_subject.$touched]"></div>
```